# Rigidbody simulation does not work on blenderkit scene but it works on my own scene

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I downloaded a blenderkit scene and I find it does not work for simple rigidbody simulation: balls fall through the ground.

What I have tried:

1. I created my own planes and set them to rigid.
2. I created a new blender file with same setup and this one works.

I am not sure what is the issue.

My file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/2zQEj5l8

[image]

This one does not fall through. https://blend-exchange.com/b/e8GxEwQW

[image]

Comment: @Chris I am new here and actually I have already upvoted for every answers. I appreacite your help.

Comment: it's ok, but in SE mathematics you clicked some more answers as ok, so you knew how to do it ;) anyway thanks for upvoting.

Comment: @Chris My bad. I should have accepted the answers sonner. Would you mind take a look?

Comment: i do already... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, found it:

the fake rooms and corridor have physics: passive -> convex hull.

Delete that rigid body physics of these objects and it works.

Convex hull means: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/convex_hull.html

So for Blender the ball is stuck inside a rigid body which makes the simulation totally weird (and this isn't physically possible)

```
Note: I have no idea where you got that scene from, but whoever build that scene has no idea how Blender physics works....
```

Here the difference between convex hull (you should really read the link i gave you to understand what convex hull does):

left: the box has rigid body convex hull. So it reacts as it is a box. right: the box has rigid body mesh: so it reacts exactly as the mesh is.

[image]

Comment: Appreciate it. I deleted those rigid body physics and it still does not work(I added those rigid body physics following tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcIZQb2b1FA). I created a new file with passive + convex hull and the ball does not fall through. Not really sure if that's the issue.

Comment: ok, please provide your updated file, so i can check it out

Comment: i updated my answer. please read my link about convex hull. You didn't understand what convex hull means. of course the convex hull of a plane...is a plane. that works. but not for more complicated meshes. And for the corridor (as in your example) it is the full room.